# Lower and Uppercase in Preg Replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How would I get this to include words that start with capital letters and lowercase? Because right now it is only lowercase.

Thanks heaps

```
$string = "you would love this @matt";
$pattern = '/(^|\W)(@([a-z]+))/';
$replacement = '$1<a href="/user/$3">$2</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `[a-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
$pattern = '/(^|\W)(@([a-zA-Z]+))/';
```

Or use the `i` modifier (it means make the match case insenstivive):

```
$pattern = '/(^|\W)(@([a-z]+))/i';
```